# How to activate Windows conda environment in WSL Ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

https://github.com/chaoyuaw/pytorch-coviar I try to install this library for my project. I installed FFmpeg already through WSL and I need to do the final step to install an actual library. However, I want to install the library for which the link I posted into specific environment so that I could use it in my project. The problem is I cannot activate my Windows environment in WSL. When I do `conda activate /mnt/c/Users/username/Anaconda3/envs/name-of-env`. I get that the path provided is not a conda environment, so I cannot do the final step of https://github.com/chaoyuaw/pytorch-coviar/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md which is to run a shell script to install specific library. I do not want to install this library in WSL itself because I will need to change through different versions of Python environments.

Answer (score -5):

Open Start Menu

Click on Settings

Click on Apps

Scroll down and click on Related settings > Programs and Features

Go to the left menu and click on Turn Windows features on or off

Scroll down and enable Windows Subsystem for Linux clicking on the left checkbox

Updated version

Comment: This is not what my question is asking